# Blank JPanel even when I draw on it

Tags: java, swing, drawing, jpanel, paintcomponent

Continuing from a simple program I started writing the other day, I have a fresh query. I would like the program to draw a black circle in the middle of a panel. Later on I will use buttons to move the circle but I'm not on that stage yet. The program runs without errors and I get a white panel with my buttons below, but no black circle in the middle of the white panel. I searched through some previous posts that recommended using paintComponent, which I've done but I'm missing something because it's not working as I expect, and repaint() doesn't work either. Any tips gratefully received.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MovingArrows extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton buttonUp, buttonDown, buttonLeft, buttonRight;
    private JPanel panel;
    private int xCircleCentre, yCircleCentre;

    final int xCircleCentreStarting = 250, yCircleCentreStarting = 250;
    final int RADIUS = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        MovingArrows frame = new MovingArrows();
        frame.setSize(550, 600);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.createGUI();
        // frame.repaint();

    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);

        window.add(panel);

        buttonUp = new JButton("Up");
        buttonDown = new JButton("Down");
        buttonLeft = new JButton("Left");
        buttonRight = new JButton("Right");
        window.add(buttonUp);
        window.add(buttonDown);
        window.add(buttonLeft);
        window.add(buttonRight);
        buttonUp.addActionListener(this);
        buttonDown.addActionListener(this);
        buttonLeft.addActionListener(this);
        buttonRight.addActionListener(this);
        // panel.repaint();

        Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();

        paintComponent(paper);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillOval(xCircleCentreStarting - RADIUS, yCircleCentreStarting
                - RADIUS, RADIUS * 2, RADIUS * 2);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        Graphics paper = panel.getGraphics();
        paper.setColor(Color.black);
        paper.fillOval(xCircleCentreStarting - RADIUS, yCircleCentreStarting
                - RADIUS, RADIUS * 2, RADIUS * 2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You try to paint on JFrame, which doesn't have `paintComponent()`, it's wrong. You need to do custom paintings in overrided `paintComponent()` method of `JPanel` for example. Read more about [custom paintings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/).

2)in your `actionPerformed()` method, for redrawing oval, you need only call `repaint()` method, that do all, you needn't get `Graphics` instance and paint by yourself.

I have changed your code, examine that :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MovingArrows extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton buttonUp, buttonDown, buttonLeft, buttonRight;
    private int xCircleCentre, yCircleCentre;

    final int xCircleCentreStarting = 250, yCircleCentreStarting = 250;
    final int RADIUS = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MovingArrows  frame = new MovingArrows();
        frame.createGUI();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        Container window = getContentPane();
        DrawHere drawHere = new DrawHere();
        drawHere.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));
        window.add(drawHere);
        window.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        buttonUp = new JButton("Up");
        buttonDown = new JButton("Down");
        buttonLeft = new JButton("Left");
        buttonRight = new JButton("Right");
        btnPanel.add(buttonUp);
        btnPanel.add(buttonDown);
        btnPanel.add(buttonLeft);
        btnPanel.add(buttonRight);
        buttonUp.addActionListener(this);
        buttonDown.addActionListener(this);
        buttonLeft.addActionListener(this);
        buttonRight.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        repaint();
    }

    class DrawHere extends JPanel {

        public DrawHere(){
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }


        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillOval(xCircleCentreStarting - RADIUS, yCircleCentreStarting
                    - RADIUS, RADIUS * 2, RADIUS * 2);

        }
    }
}
```

and it's look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply and code. I'll try and work my way through it and hopefully I'll understand. I didn't come across the link you gave me...I read some other guides but I still couldn't figure out my mistake from them.

Comment: Been through it and I think I understand it. It's so weird not having direct control over when your program paints on the panel. I'd also like to think you for sorting out the buttons and putting them on a panel for me - I haven't read into frame layouts yet and this was something I was going to do soon.